# Discord.js voice crashing after playing audio for a little

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So if i play a song, after about a minute the bot simply crashes and says it "aborted"

```
music = {
            "resource": createAudioResource(ytdl(parameters[0], {filter: "audioonly"}), {inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary, inlineVolume: true}),
            "connection": joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
                guildId: message.channel.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: message.channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
            })
        }
        const player = createAudioPlayer();
        player.play(music["resource"]);
        music["connection"].subscribe(player);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes its extremely long:
https://pastebin.com/6V7TrAGv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using play-dl instead of ytdl